# Should an API Gateway Communicate via a Queue or directly to other μServices?

Tags: microservices, message-queue, cqrs, gateway, event-sourcing

I was wondering which of my two methods is more appropriate, or is there event another one?

### (1) Direct

[image: direct communication]
**Direct communication between `GATEWAY` and `μSERVICE A`**

1. `UI` sends `HTTP` request to `GATEWAY`
2. `GATEWAY` sends `HTTP` request to `μSERVICE A`
3. `μSERVICE A` returns either `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`
4. Event is stored in `EVENT STORE` and published to `QUEUE`
5. `PROJECTION DATABASE` is updated
6. Other `μSERVICES` might consume event

---

### (2) Events

[image: queue communication]
**Event-based communication via a message queue**

1. `UI` sends `HTTP` request to `GATEWAY`
2. `GATEWAY` published event to `QUEUE`
3. `μSERVICE A` consumes event
4. Event is stored in `EVENT STORE` and published to `QUEUE`
5. `PROJECTION DATABASE` is updated
6. Other `μSERVICES` might consume event
7. `GATEWAY` consumes event and sends response (`SUCCESS` or `ERROR`) to `UI`

---

I am really sorry if I misunderstood some concept, I am relatively new to this style of architecture.

Thanks in advance for every help! :)

Comment: Hmm... what gateway are you planning to use? I don't think putting all your business  and event logic in a gateway is a good idea, even if it is possible.

Comment: What do you mean with 'what gateway'? So you would rather recommend the first approach?

Comment: @Seth You might checkout my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56654068/8586803

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Second approach is a preferred way and is async approach.

**Direct**

In first approach your microsvc B and C wait for the event to get published . The scalability of this system is directly dependent on microsvc A. what if microsvc A is down or falling behind writing events to queue? it's like single point of failure and bottleneck. you can't scale system easily.

**Events**

In microservices we keep system async so they can scale. 
Gateway should be writing to the queue using pub/sub and all these microservices can use events at same time. system over all is more robust and can be scaled.

Comment: Great, thank you! One more question: When UI makes e. g. a post request, does the gateway wait and later return the HTTP response to the UI (success or error)?

Comment: That's right . Gateway will be the entry and exit point for your request/Response. You can even aggregate response from different services at gateway. It normally also works for auth/authorization . Make sure gateway is highly available. It can be a bottleneck since if it goes down user can't reach any of your backend services.

Comment: It would be a pleasure if you could check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56654068/8586803